# if statement to compare Character Length of the_content();

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, custom-post-type

I need to compare the **Character Length** of my `Custom Post Type post->content`
I have displayed the content by limiting to 200 words.

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); 
echo substr($content, 0, 200); ?>
```

However, I need to trigger something if character exceeds 200 words.

**Similar to like this:**

`if( character_length > 200 ) , Popup link to display the whole content.`

I searched on **StackOverflow** and **Google** but couldn't find the right solution.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) function to find out how long a string is:

```
if (strlen($content) > 200) {
    // Popup link to display the whole content...
}
```